# Compositum of a separable extension $K$ with a finite degree field $L$, is it separable over $L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a (finite degree) separable extension, and $L$ is any finite degree extension of $F$.

Prove or disprove : Compositum of $K$ and $L$ (meaning $KL$), is separable over $L$.

I have a feeling the claim is false, and my intuition (which could be wrong) is as follows:

By hypothesis every $k\in K$ satisfy a separable polynomial in $F[t]$ which in term can be viewed as a $L$ polynomial. But I dont see why every $k' \in KL$ must also satisfy some $L$ separable polynomial, I mean what if $k' \notin K$ ?

If my intuition is correct, then I am having some trouble providing a neat counterexample. So any help in that regard is deeply appreciated.

If my intuition is wrong, then I would be grateful if perhaps I can be provided with some guideline on how to prove the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition was not correct.

Start with your finite separable extension $K\supset F$. This extension is simple, i.e. there is $\alpha\in K$ with $K=F(\alpha)$. Separability also means that the minimal polynomial $f$ for $\alpha$ over $F$ has all roots distinct. Now clearly, $KL=L(\alpha)$, and the $L$-minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, call this $g$, certainly is a divisor of $f$, and thus its roots are distinct. So $L(\alpha)$ is separable over $L$. And there you are.

Note that $L$ did not need to be finite over $F$ here.

Comment: My initial attempts was trying to verify for any members of $KL$, but your argument seems to suggest I need only verify separability for the generator(s). Am I correct in my understanding ?

Comment: Sure. The way I look at (and teach) these things is to play against each other the concepts of separability of an element and separability of an extension. The latter may be defined as the equality between the field extension degree $[K:F]$ and the separable degree, $[K:F]_s$, defined as the number of distinct $F$-morphisms of $K$ into an algebraically closed extension of $F$.